# Adding lines to a qplot that don't cover whole axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add partial lines (dont expand whole plot) to a scatterplot. I have two separate plots working for this, but can't figure out how to join them together:

First plot -

```
p = qplot(x, y, data=data) + theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
lines = data.frame(x = c(-2,-2,5), y = c(0,2,2))
```

Second plot -

```
lines = data.frame(x = c(-2,-2,5), y = c(0,2,2))
base = ggplot(lines, aes(x, y))
base + geom_path(size = 1)
```

How to overlay them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
p = qplot(x, y, data=data) + theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
lines = data.frame(x = c(-2,-2,5), y = c(0,2,2))
p+geom_line(data = lines, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Taking an example dataset `mydf`:

```
Dept <- c("Res","Bankings","Customer","Legal","Collection","Business")
YScore <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
XScore <- c(2,1,3,1,2,4)
mydf<-data.frame(Dept,YScore,XScore)

p = qplot(XScore, YScore, data=mydf) + theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
lines = data.frame(x = c(-2,-2,5), y = c(0,2,2))
p+geom_line(data = lines, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal. I get an error 'Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Type' not found'

Comment: please type `dput(data)` in your console and provide the output here

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal. I just realized that it does not work when I set p to what I was really trying (p = qplot(x, y, data=data, colour=Type, shape=Type) + theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)). It works when p is equal to what you set it. I simplified it for this question online! Why would this be?

Comment: Also, dput(data) output is: structure(list(x = c(1, 4, 5), y = c(-2, -1, 5)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"). Sorry!

Comment: this is happening because there is no `Type` column in your data. Add `data$Type<-c("a","b","a")`. Then try `p = qplot(x, y, data=data, colour=Type, shape=Type) + theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)`